# Adding a separate line of regression to ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Assuming I have a data frame with the following column headings: Height, Weight, Gender.

I am using ggplot to create a scatter graph.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = height, y = weight , col = gender)) +
 geom_point() +
 theme_classic() +
 geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

This plots two lines of regression one for male and female. I would like to add another regression for overall comparing height and weight. How do I do this?

Comment: Please add code to reproduce a minimal version of the df dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another `geom_smooth` with `col` set to a static label. This overrides the first `aes(col = gender)` argument, puts all observations back in one group and gives it the label you want to use:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, col = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(aes(col = "Overall"), method = "lm", se = FALSE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Edit: Following up questions below, this also works with `scale_colour_lancet`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  modelr::add_predictions(model = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, 
                          data = iris)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, col = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_line(aes(y = pred)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(col = "Overall"), method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  ggsci::scale_color_lancet()
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The `geom_smooth` used above does `lm(y ~ x)` for each grouping automatically, in this case giving the equivalent lines for `lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width*Species)`. To get `lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species)` a simple way would be to use `modelr::add_predictions()` to create a `pred` variable for y values before passing into `ggplot`.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your help! One more question for my data set. The “Overall” category is not appearing on the legend? 

Is there an extra step?

Comment: There's a few possibilities of why it might be - in the example above it appears as the `aes(col)` calls across the two `geom_smooth()`s adds "Overall" naturally to the list of breaks to pass to the legend. If you use `scale_colour_manual` and don't assign it a value it might not appear. Also, make sure it's assigned within the `aes()` bracket. If you're still stuck feel free to append the new code to your question to see if there's something missing.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have an example of your dataset you can post we can try on your data?

Comment: I am using ```scale_colour_lancet()``` Does this need to be adjusted?

May I also ask how would add the following regression lines provided by the function ```lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + Species)``` for each species?

Comment: have done a wee edit to see if it helps. `scale_colour_lancet` as above adds the "Overall" label fine. Also, to get that particular formula you've described I think you'd have to make the predictions before passing to `ggplot`. Does that work? Do post latest code as well if it's still not working and we can see if there's a bug or a missing element.

Comment: I determined the issue why the overall is not appearing in the legend.

If do 

```geom_smooth(aes(col = "Overall"), method = "lm", linetype = "dashed", se = FALSE)
```

It appears but it removes one of the categories becomes blank.

If i do ```geom_smooth(aes(col = "Overall"), method = "lm", colour = "black", linetype = "dashed", se = FALSE) ``` it does not show. I have 9 categories

Comment: Ah that makes sense! the Lancet palette only has 9 colours according to the help file. So it can't assign 10 unique colours and subsequently drops one. Another palette would work then if it provided 10+ colours.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much

Comment: If I have a data frame containing columns Width, Length, Colour. With the values in colour - red, blue, green.

I am using the following regression:
```lm(Width~Length+Colour, df)```

I would like to change the reference level of the dummy variable to green.

Comment: the solution would be changing the `Colour` factor levels to make 'green' the base level. If it's a factor already you can use `mutate(Colour = forcats::fct_relevel(Colour, "green"))` or create a factor from a character variable and make green the first case. Hope that works! It's developing into quite a different question now - if you have further problems with the factor reordering then do put in a new question. Gives more space to work through rather than pack all into comments :)

Comment: (PS - if you like the colours of the Lancet palette and want to squeeze a tenth colour out of it you can replace `scale_colour_lancet` with `scale_colour_manual(values = colorRampPalette(pal_lancet()(9))(10))` - this takes the 9 colours of the Lancet palette and shuffles them around to make 10 across the same rough spectrum)

Comment: Hi, I wanted to add a regression to my plot with more variables e.g. lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal Width + Species), where species is a dummy variable. I want the regression line to show the coefficient of Sepal.Width for all species when all other variables are held constant